# Replace-all-occurences keyboard shortcut for Atom under Linux

Tags: atom-editor

In Mac OS X <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> replaces a word in the whole file. What's the alternative to that in Linux?

I tried to check the keybindings, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to active the **Key Binding Resolver** to look for the actual function bound to the shortcut on your Mac and search the function on Linux Atom to figure out what the key combination is.

Alternatively, your can search all your key binding here (see screenshot below) which accept both key combination and command name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using **ctrl + e** when you are on a word will open the find and replace panel for this word.

Then use tab to go into the "replace in current buffer field", type your replacement word.

Finally, hit enter to replace the occurrences one by one, or **ctrl + enter** to replace all.